# NodeJS: MySQL-Query crashes

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm new to NodeJS and currently testing with MySQL.

When I'm requesting Content from the database to render it to my page, everything works fine. (/test01).

But now I'm trying to get to values from my database to store them in a cookie. But then my application crashes.

I would be glad if someone could help me

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const router  = express.Router();

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "data"
});

db.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log("Error");
    }
    else{
        console.log("Connect");
    }
})

router.get('/test01', (req, res) => {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM uebersicht',(err, results)=>{
        res.render("page",{results:results});
    });

router.get('/test02', (req, res) => {
    var data = req.cookies.id;

    db.query("SELECT vorname FROM uebersicht WHERE id ='" + data + "'",(err, results)=>{ 
        var x = results[0].vorname;
        res.cookie('vorname', x, { path: '/',});
        console.log("Test1");
    });
    db.query("SELECT nachname FROM uebersicht WHERE id ='" + data + "'",(err, results)=>{
        var y = results[0].nachname;
        res.cookie('nachname', y, { path: '/',});
        console.log("Test2"); 
    }); 

    res.send("Hallo");
});

module.exports = router;
db.end;
```

I tried to put the res.cookie outside of the query but then I got the problem, that the res.cookie was executed before the query finished.

Comment: please post the complete error message, also a create table would help also

Comment: In Chrome I get "VM45:5 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.". In the VS Code terminal I only get "[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..."

Comment: A guess into the wild: Your `res.send("Hallo");` is executed before the db queries finish. This sends the http header, which does not allow to set cookies anymore, because cookies are basicly just http header. This crashes node with something like "HTTP Allready sent". As @nbk said, post the complete terminal/shell output. Not just one line.

Comment: With "create table" you mean my MySQL table?

Comment: @Marc How can I change that, so that the res.send("Hallo"); is waiting until the rest is executed?

Comment: @Nik98 Switch to promises or combine the query that both your Nachname und Vorname are fetched from one query.

Comment: @Marc I will try that - thank you

Comment: @Marc that helped - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are many modules that make handling cookies much easier and secure but this should help at least for the approach you're currently using. As others noted, `node` is asynchronous and if you you call `res.send` outside of or before data you need is complete you will get the results you are experiencing.

```js
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const router  = express.Router();

const db = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
  user: process.env.DB_USER || 'local_user',
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'local_password',
  database: process.env.DB_NAME || 'local_database',
  multipleStatements: true, 
  charset: 'utf8mb4' // necessary if you might need support for emoji characters
});

router.get('/test01', (req, res) => {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM uebersicht',(err, results)=>{
    res.render("page",{results:results});
  });
});

router.get('/test02', (req, res) => {
  let cookie_id = req.cookies.id;

  db.query(
    'SELECT vorname, nachname FROM uebersicht WHERE id = ?', cookie_id, function(error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log(results);

      let x = results[0].vorname;
      let y = results[0].nachname;
      res.cookie('vorname', x, { path: '/',});
      res.cookie('nachname', y, { path: '/',});
      res.send("Hallo");
    });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```